# With NetworkX' DiGraph, how to find single input leaf-nodes starting from a certain node?

Tags: python, networkx

Taking the following graph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)
```

which visualized gives:

[image]

I'd like to find the leaf-nodes which only have incoming-edges from within the "sub-graph" starting from `1`.

In my example it has to find `4` but not `5`. `5` is a child of `2` which has `3` as second input.

I think it should be something with successors and the in_degree but I'm such a newbie to NetworkX that it is quite hard to find the right algorithm.

Another example:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(1,7)
G.add_edge(7,6)

G.add_edge(1,8)
G.add_edge(8,7)
G.add_edge(8,6)
G.add_edge(4,9)
G.add_edge(4,10)
G.add_edge(5,10)
```

[image]

Here it should find `9` and `6`. But not `10` (because of `3` being parent of `2` being a parent `5`.

Comment: I would help if you created a sample DiGraph that way we can create reproducible code.

Comment: @ScottBoston I updated my question.

Comment: Now that is an interesting problem.  Upvoted and marked as my favorite.  I think we are going to have to traverse the descendant nodes to see if that branches to another head node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this bit of logic:

```
def find_leafnodes(G):
    leafnode = []

    for i in G.nodes:
        head =  []
        if nx.descendants(G, i) == set(): #find all leaf nodes
            for a in nx.ancestors(G, i):  #get all ancestors for leaf node
                if nx.ancestors(G, a) == set():  #Determine if ancestor is a head node
                    head.append(a)
        if len(head) == 1: #if this leaf had only one head then append to leafnode
            leafnode.append(i)
    return leafnode
```

Input:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)

find_leafnodes(G)
# [4]

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(3,2)
G.add_edge(1,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)
G.add_edge(1,7)
G.add_edge(7,6)

G.add_edge(1,8)
G.add_edge(8,7)
G.add_edge(8,6)
G.add_edge(4,9)
G.add_edge(4,10)
G.add_edge(5,10)

find_leafnodes(G)
# [6, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, it works. However `find_leavenodes()` is missing the 'starting-node'-argument. Imagine adding edge `[3, 11]`. If I'm looking for genetically pure offspring of `1`, I don't want to find `11`.

Comment: I add and `root == head[0]` in the `if len(head) == 1`-condition and it works.

Answer (score 7):

The following code is more compact and works faster than the other answer.

```
roots = [v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0]
leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for the green ✓) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful. Also while this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098), as that helps to improve the quality of your post. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about Stack Overflow and also refer to the [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).